# fetch the result based on the user postalcode

Tags: php, mysql

I've following table

```
Shop   latitude         longitude
A       45.326874     -75.723473
B       43.757496     -79.481728
C       45.409691     -75.728264
```

I need to fetch the result based on the postalcode given by use by distance. I tried many ways but no result. Can anybody helps me?

......

Comment: Yes. Show us the many ways you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the latitude and longitude of user postal code by using this url example:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=canada&components=postal_code:<user_postalcode>&sensor=false`

Then fetch the result using the below query

```
SELECT Shop, latitude, longitude, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lng ) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance ,latitude,longitude FROM <YOUR TABLE> ORDER BY distance ASC ;
```

I didnt check it well. But i think it will helps your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.